# To avoid components overlapping in angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have two components called `customer-details` and `customer-bookings` which are called by their selectors in `app.component.html` file as shown in below code

```
     <app-customer-details></app-customer-details>
     <app-customer-bookings></app-customer-bookings>
```

The components should look like this(i,e one below the other).

[image]

But it is overlapping like this.

[image]

Here i am facing overlapping issues,I tried to solve it by setting **height to 50vh** for each component. But i want to solve this overlapping issue without setting the height manually.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/list-examples-6lctnu?file=app/app.component.html) link.

Comment: Remove `table{
  position:absolute;
}` from your `customer-details.component.css`

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this from your table style:

```
position:absolute;
```

in customer-details.component.css

Answer (score 1):

Noting to do with the component.
Just modify the CSS.

```css
table{
  /* position:absolute; */
}
```