# Ionic 4 html is overlapping, css not working on padding

Tags: html, css, ionic4, user-experience, angular8

I have a `base component` which have a `header component selector` and then `ion-router-outlet`.
I would like to add an any html card on a first page which is `Home` as my routes.
If I place html card on `base component` then html output seems fine but when I place html card on Home component which will be a child for base, my card renders behind the header or we can say overlap as in the image below:
Ionic 4 and Angular 8 is used.

[image: Html overlap issue]

Comment: Please, share css of HTMLCard.component.html and see more details.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your HTML card doesn't have in the own selector css some:

```
display:block;
position:relative;
```

Or you have **position:absolute** to HTMLCard.component.html. Remove this!

So that the other components understand that something is above and they can position me immediately below.

Normally that happens when (in this case: **home.component.html**) does not relatively detect an element rather than respect and place itself below.

- Link reference:
  [To avoid components overlapping in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52495000/to-avoid-components-overlapping-in-angular)

Comment: Nope it's not working. I've added a class to my htmlCard's root element with given css and checked for any absolute on Header

Comment: @AbhishekChokra Could you apply this class in runtime mode from the Developer Tools of the browser?

2 things happen: Either the HTMLCard is in absolute css or the HomeComponent is, but neither of them is being recognized side by side.